# Integrate interface to get function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

I am new to react and JavaScript and I want to integrate User interface into my UserContext so I can get my IsAdmin variable all along the project(to do some filters). Any ideas how I can do that? I ve tried different methods but I can't get it right.

```
import axios from "axios";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
interface User{
    name: string;
  email: string;
  password: string;
  isAdmin: boolean;
}

export const UserContext = React.createContext<any[]>([]);
export const UserProvider = (props: any) => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    // const loadedToken = localStorage.getItem("logInToken")
    //   ? localStorage.getItem("logInToken")
    //   : sessionStorage.getItem("logInToken");

    // const config = { headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${loadedToken}` } };
    axios
      .get("http://localhost:4000/meetings/")
      .then((res) => {
        const user = [];
        for (let key in res.data) {
          user.push({ ...res.data[key], id: key });
        }
        setUser(res.data);
        // console.log(posts);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <UserContext.Provider value={user}>{props.children}</UserContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can type your `user` state variable like this

```
const [user, setUser] = useState<User[]>([]);
```

To type the context (where context is created)

```
const UserContext: React.Context<User> = createContext();
```

Comment: should i also add it to props on UserProvider?

Comment: No, you can't pass an interface as a prop but you can also type the context, will update answer